# How to disable a variable after the user has it correct in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am making a little game in which the user has to guess the right grid, when you connect it says "hit". After 3 hits you sink the "ship". It isn't anything special, however what I was wondering is: How can I disable a variable (or not make it valid) when the user has it correct? So for example: `var x = 5;` and the user types in 5, so this should be correct. But if you were to press 5 twice more (the hit count will come on 3) it will sink my ship without you guessing the other 2 grids. So my question: How can you `disable` a variable?

```
let isSunk = false;
let guess;
let location1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let location2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let location3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let guesses = 0;
let hit = 0;



while (isSunk == false) {
    guess = prompt("Try to sink me!");

    guesses += 1;

    if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
        hit += 1;
        window.alert("HIT!");
    } else {
        window.alert("MISS!");
    }

    if (hit == 3) {
        window.alert("you sunk my ship!");
        isSunk = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep the state of the location with the location so you can stop checking it again. Location should be a collection or object, and it keep track of the state of each location. Maybe it even has methods that do things like check to see if there is a hit or miss, and if the entire location is sunk. Part of the state maintenance is ignoring multiple hits to same coordinate of the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring your location at top , declare them in your while loop, So whenever your loop will execute it will give you new numbers , so user can't guess .

Comment: and if you want make more hard , just use one location ,btw wlecome.

Comment: How do you make sure you don't pick the same random number twice?

Comment: I don't @MarkMeyer. I am practicing javascript (therefore this very basic example and most likely the simple solution which I couldnt find). :)

Comment: For that you have to make a new variable name pveLoc and do comparison of old random num with new one if they are same just do same process again , if not then pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Think about modifying your approach to the problem. Do not allow the user to enter the same value.

```js
let isSunk = false;
let guess;
let location1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let location2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let location3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
let guesses = 0;
let hit = 0;

//Add array of past guesses
let userGuesses = [];

while (isSunk == false) {
  guess = prompt("Try to sink me!");

  guesses += 1;

  //Check array of past guesses
  if (userGuesses.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
    window.alert("YOU ALREADY TRIED THAT!");
  } else if (guess == location1 || guess == location2 || guess == location3) {
    hit += 1;
    window.alert("HIT!");
  } else {
    window.alert("MISS!");
  }

  if (hit == 3) {
    window.alert("you sunk my ship!");
    isSunk = true;
  }

  //Add guess to array of past guesses
  userGuesses.push(guess);
}
```